# Flattening of dictionary of dictionaries raises AttributeError

Tags: python, list, dictionary, flatten

I have a dictionary:

```
dict1 = {
    'conf1' : {'subconf11' : True, 'subconf12' : False}, 
    'conf2' : False, 
    'conf3' : {'subconf31' : True, 'subconf32' : False, 'subconf33' : False}, 
    'conf4' : 'On'
}
```

I want to flatten it to a list of tuples, such that:

```
list1 = [
    ('conf1',('subconf11',True)),
    ('conf1',('subconf12',False)),
    ('conf2',False),
    ('conf3',('subconf31',True)),
    ('conf3',('subconf32',False)),
    ('conf3',('subconf33',False)),
    ('conf4','On')
]
```

I tried something like:

```
primary_conf_list = list(dict1.keys())
list2 = [(i,list[dict1[i].items()]) for i in primary_conf_list]
```

But understandably it throws me error for those where the value is not a dictionary but either a bool or a string value. For example `dict1['conf2']` and `dict1['conf4']`.

Here is the exact error message:

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: You need nested loops to create a tuple for each element in the nested dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if the value is a dictionary. If it is, use a nested loop to add elements to the result for each item.

```
list2 = []
for key, val in dict1.items():
    if isinstance(val, dict):
        for subkey, subval in val.items():
            list2.append((key, (subkey, subval)))
    else:
        list2.append(key, val)
```

Comment: @Barmer thank you, this is what I wanted. One question for my knowledge, how is `isinstance(val, dict)` different from `type(val) is dict` in behavior. I have seen cases (especially cpython scenarios) where the `type()` match doesn't work. But the isinstance() works for almost all practical purposes.

Comment: `isinstance()` will work for subclasses, such as `defaultdict`.

Comment: @Barmer Can you please transform your answer into a recursive code, for dictionary of dictionaries. For example `subconf31` can be a dictionary of dictionaries itself. example: `'subconf31' : { 'subconf311' : { 'subconf3111' : True, 'subconf31112' : False}, 'subconf312' :  True}`